# mysqli->query(); works sometimes

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

i have a kind of problems here and i don't know how to solve it... google said nothing and the search function here didn't shown me anything...

i use this code

```
$GAME_DB = new mysqli($__CONFIG['MySQL']['HOST'], $__CONFIG['MySQL']['USER'], $__CONFIG['MySQL']['PASS'], $__CONFIG['MySQL']['DB']['GAME']);
if($GAME_DB->connect_errno) { echo $GAME_DB->connect_error; exit; }

$VILLAGE_DATA['villageID'] = $mysqli->real_escape_string($VILLAGE_DATA['villageID']);
$query = "SELECT name, level, time FROM actions WHERE type='build' AND villageID='".$VILLAGE_DATA['villageID']."'";
if($result = $GAME_DB->query($query))
    {
    // table header
    while($row = $result->fetch_row())
        {
        // some rows in here
        }
    // table footer
    }
```

there aren't any syntax errors in that query and the results are there!
sometimes the query is successful and i see my table but sometimes (for example: when i reload) i receive the error message `Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now`

how can this just work "sometimes"? where is my problem?

Comment: Use better error handling.

Comment: i'm still by reworking the code ;)

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/commands-out-of-sync.html

> If you get Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now in
>   your client code, you are calling client functions in the wrong order.
>
> This can happen, for example, if you are using mysql_use_result() and
>   try to execute a new query before you have called mysql_free_result().
>   It can also happen if you try to execute two queries that return data
>   without calling mysql_use_result() or mysql_store_result() in between.

But from the code you've posted I don't see how this could happen. Either there's more code than what you've posted and something there is happening out of order, or your MySQL connections are being improperly established/pooled/persisted somewhere outside of PHP.

Comment: i don't understand that good enough to get a result... should i change something on my source code there or what can i do to solve my problem? i don't have used anything of the functions in the problem description on the link...

Comment: @AlexRuhl Those are not PHP functions, those are C functions that PHP calls internally. I'm saying your code is probably fine, but there may be some connection handling/pooling/proxying happening outside of PHP that is going sideways. Contact your host or IT dept.

Comment: if i close the connection and connect right after it again with the same code (like line 1 and 2 in my code right above) it works all the time... what could that mean?